# How to compare integral for decreasing function on some ball?

Tags: analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ and $s<0.$ Assume that $  |\text{supp} \ f | \leq M^k A^d$ fix $k>0.$

> Can we say that  $$ \|f\|_{L^2} \leq \| (1+|x|^2)^s\|_{L^2( \{|x|\leq M^{k/d} A\})} \leq C(M) \| (1+|x|^2)^s\|_{L^2( \{|x|\leq A\})}$$?
>   If so what is $C(M) $ constant depending on $M$?

Note. I think the above first inequality can be proved using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3575079/int-35-1-xi2s-d-xi-leq-int-11-1-xi2s-d-xi-for-s0)